# My drop down menu isn't dropping down (its appearing sideways) & how to sticky the bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've created a navigation bar, but the drop down isn't quiet functioning properly. the drop down isn't a list downwards, but rather drops down sideways (messing up the entire navbar). What could the issue be?

I also have a follow up question on how I can sticky the nav bar. So, when a user scroll down, there is a small animation of a background fade in. Then if u scroll back up, it fades out.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');

body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 background-color: #ccc;
}

header {
 height: 100vh;
}

.top-nav {
 position: fixed;
 width: 74%;
 left: 50%;
 margin-left: -37%;
 line-height: 60px;
 background-color: red;
}

.top-nav ul {
 float: right;
 margin: 0;
 padding-right: 42px;
 list-style: none;
}

.top-nav ul li {
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 16px 32px;
}

.top-nav ul li a {
 font-family: Roboto, arial;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-weight: 500;
 color: #fff;

 text-decoration: none;
 display: block;
}

.top-nav ul li ul {
 display: none;
}

.top-nav ul li:hover ul {
 display: block;
}

.top-nav-logo {
 position: fixed;
 width: 187px;
 height: 50px;
 float: left;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 16px 48px;
 background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<header>
 
 <div class="top-nav">

  <div class="top-nav-logo">
   <img src="/logo.png">
  </div>

  <ul>
   <li>
    <a href="#">Section 1</a>
   </li>

   <li>
    <a href="#">Section 2</a>
   </li>

   <li>
    <a href="#">More</a>
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#">More 1</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">More 2</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>

   <li>
    <a href="#">Section 3</a>
   </li>
   
  </ul>

 </div>

</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this css to mange drop down and apply position relative for ul li(dropdown)

```
.top-nav ul li ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: How can I make the drop down centered (to its main section). Also on the sides of the drop down menu, there is a huge gap

Answer (score 0):

First u need to give position: relative to list which has ul inside it, then apply position: absolute to the child ul. Add the following code in the style.css, it will work

```
.top-nav ul ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 30px;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
}

.top-nav ul li:nth-child(3) {
    position: relative;
}
.top-nav ul ul {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}
.top-nav ul ul li {
    padding: 0;
}
```